# How can I deactivate another system as my primary ps4

Tags: ps4

How can I deactivate my account from another system. On my PlayStation it says you have already activated another system as your primary ps4 with your account. To activate this system... Also I just recently purchased a PlayStation plus subscription and I want to play online with my brothers but having difficulties to play together

Answer (score 5):

As seen on the [Playstation Manuals](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/activation.html) website:

- Select Settings > Playstation Network/Account Management > Activate as your Primary PS4 > Deactivate.

If you run into an issue deactivating your PS4 you can contact Playstation Customer Support for further instructions.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the system you can log into your account from a PC and deactivate the system from there. You are only allowed to deactivate once every 6 months or so. If you are still within that time you'll have to open a ticket with Sony to do it for you.

Comment: Sony support will not deactivate it for you. They will point you to the self-service web page which upholds the 6-month waiting period. http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Network-Support/Another-PS4-activated-as-primary-we-only-have-one-so-how-do-I/td-p/45007011

Comment: Sony will deactivate it for you if you put the ticket in. I was under my 6 month waiting period and put the ticket in. I was given a follow up email the next day that my issue had been resolved by Sony deactivating all the PS's under my account.